# Build path using google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internationalization

I have a small function to get a route on Google Maps. It works fine when I have English addresses (I mean between two streets in England or other EU\NA countries). But I have a problem when I have Russian addresses which were written on English. Like Example:

- from = 'Belarus, Minsk, Russianova, 1'
- to = 'Belarus, Minsk, Nikiforova, 1'.

I *can* find these addresses on Google Maps but I *can not* build a route and the status results in `NOT_FOUND`.

It's not a problem when I use a library to translate from English to Russian, but that doesn't solve all problems. For example:

- `Belarussia => Minsk` and `Belarus => Brest` do **not** work
- `Belarus => Minsk` and `Belarussia, Brest` **do** work

Also it doesn't work with marks at all.

Could you help me to build routes using addresses without having to guess what form of one city works with another?

The function I'm using now is this:

```js
function getRout(from, to) {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 53.9,
      lng: 27.6
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsService.route({
    origin: from,
    destination: to,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert(status);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try spelling it differently: 'Belarus, Minsk, Rusijanava, 1'

Comment: it works fine but sometimes people make mistakes when write Russian street name on English and default google maps can work with it. Also I still have a problem with 'Bielorussia, Brest'.

Comment: @EvgeniyL - Have you looked at the Places API? You can implement the _[Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)_ (or _[Autocomplete Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)_) in order to help your users to find the right spelling.

Comment: not in my case, I get addresses from remote database